# How to save the UIViewController state after pressing the back button in a UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

Example:

1. Enter your name in the first view controller.
2. After entering your name, you push the navigation controller to the birthday view, in which you input your birthday.
3. Press the back button to the first view controller.
4. Then push to the birthday view controller again displaying the input that you had previously input.

This was an example from Snapchat's sign up logic.

How is this possible? Do I need to subclass UINavigationController and tinker with the behavior?

Comment: Just store your value in NSUserDefault and access it anywhere in any controller.

Comment: You can also use singleton to store value if you dont want it to persist once app get terminated

Comment: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:YOURTEXTFIELD.text forKey:@"Birthdate"]; and retrive this birthdate NSString *YOURVARIABLE = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] ValueForKey:@"Birthdate"];

Answer (score 0):

You can store your birthdate in a NSUserDefault like this

```
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_txt_birthday.text forKey:SIGNUP_DATEOFBIRTH];
```

and retrieve it in your birthday view controller like this

```
NSString *strDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SIGNUP_DATEOFBIRTH];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to store birthday then you can save it in NSUserDefault. But if you want to store the whole state of your controller with more UI elements and values then you should go for `App State Restoration`.
There are tutorial available for this..

> https://www.raywenderlich.com/117471/state-restoration-tutorial
>
> http://useyourloaf.com/blog/state-preservation-and-restoration/